# UIImagePickerController get UIImage with it's overlay

Tags: iphone, ios

Please help.

No one seems to have a successful working answer to the following:

I get an image from the iPhone camera using UIImagePickerController. When taking the image there is an overlay present. The overlay is simply a subclassed UIImageView with various gestures attached.

When I take the image, how do I add the overlay to the image in precisely where it is on the device screen?

Any help much appreciated,

LB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm writing this away from xcode, so it may need tweaks...

Create a UIView class with UIImage properties, picture & overlay, & call it something like compositorView. From the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method in your UIImagePickerController delegate, set the picture property of compositorView to the photo you've just taken, & the overlay property to whatever image you're using. Then ask compositorView for its composedImage, & that should be it...

(You'll need the QuartzCore framework)

```
@synthesize picture = _picture;
@synthesize overlay = _overlay;


-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    [_picture drawInRect:frame];
    [_overlay drawInRect:frame];

}


-(UIImage *)composedImage
{
    CGSize pageSize = self.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pageSize, NO, 2.0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return theImage;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that- I got it going using the above.. Thanks. LB